# scala implicit completing itself?

Tags: scala, null, implicit

I used that kind of line to test my implicits making it implicit by copy-paste accident. It took me quite some time to figure out, why this compiles despite me not expecting it to compile:

```
> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_66).
... skipped some comment lines ...

scala> case object Foo
defined object Foo

scala> object Bar { implicit val f: Foo.type = implicitly[Foo.type] }
defined object Bar

scala> val x = Bar.f
x: Foo.type = null

scala>
```

I would expect Bar to fail compilation, because there is NO implicit val of type `Foo.type` (the case object is NOT declared implicit).

For me it looks like the compiler uses f's own declaration (left hand side) to complete its implementation (right hand side).

Is this really the intended behavior? At runtime this results in unexpected behavior with `null` values (mostly NPEs for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `f` is declared as `implicit`. So in a way the right hand side of `implicit val f: Foo.type = implicitly[Foo.type]` resolves to the implicit val `f` itself !

If you remove the `implicit` from that line the compilation would fail.
What i am wondering is why are you using such a line though.

This is definitely a issue to me. Someone looks like already took a note last year though.

[Enhancement Request](https://github.com/scala/scala-abide/issues/56)

Comment: the mentioned issue is labelled as 'enhancement'. I would consider this a bug. Any chance to raise its importance?

Comment: i agree its an issue. I think you can go ahead and log an issue with them. Or maybe add a comment to that `enhancement` request . i would do that too.

Comment: If it's a bug, it's in the spec, not the code. The val definition belongs to the outer scope of the implicitly, so it's valid as a candidate for the search. Common workaround is to not annotate the target value, `implicit val f = implicitly[Foo.type]` would work, as in fail to compile, since the compiler doesn't know that `f` will be of the desired type.

Comment: Great point.  Up. But i still think this needs to be handled clearly.

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya consider this: `implicit val someFormat: Format[List[Foo]] = (__ \ "foo" \ "bar").format[List[Foo]]` to extract a list of objects nested within some JSON structure.

Comment: In one scenario I found removing the explicit type from `f` and having it infer from the right-hand side generated a compiler error instead of no compiler error.